# Check whether a link is disabled using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to check whether a link's disabled attribute is set, in the following code,

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbtnNext" disabled="disabled">Next</a>
```

However on the last page if I execute,

```
next_pg=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbtnNext']")
next_pg.click()
print next_pg.is_enabled()
```

I get ***True*** as the output, which should not be the case.
Also, only on the last page is the ***Next*** coded as given above, in all other pages it is coded as follows, due to which on checking the is_enabled() tag, an error is produced.

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbtnNext" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lbtnNext','')">
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27307235/2676531) to get the attributes of the tag:

```
attrs = driver.execute_script('var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', next_pg)
```

and check for the presence of the `disabled` tag and it's value:

```
if 'disabled' in attrs and attrs['disabled'] == 'disabled':
    # ...
```