# Selenium - How to find a list of an element's CURRENT attributes

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, attributes, webdriver

Building on the question asked in [Selenium webdriver: How do I find ALL of an element's attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307131/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-find-all-of-an-elements-attributes)

When I use this answer I get the expected result of the elements attributes. However it isn't current, in other words not what I see on the screen.

For example:

```
>attrs = driver.execute_script('var items = {}; for (index = 0; index <arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', vlan)
>print attrs
{ u'name': u'PixF1InterfaceVLAN', u'value': u'1',}
```

However if I look at the same element 'vlan':

```
>vlan.get_attribute("value")
 u'10'
```

Which is what I see on the screen. My question is how can I update the Javascript code so that it shows the correct list of attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am making the informed guess that the element you are looking at is an `input` element, which has been manipulated somehow to change its value. The problem is that Selenium in trying to be helpful unhelpfully confuses the issue. Let me explain.

The JavaScript code you use **does** return all the values of the **attributes**. Here's the deal though: when an `input` element's value changes, it `value` *attribute* does not change but its `value` *property* does. It is the *property* that contains the current value of the `input` element. You access it as the `.value` field on the DOM node that corresponds to the element. You could do:

```
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].value;', vlan)
```

to return the value of this property.

But how come `vlan.get_attribute("value")` works? When you execute `.get_attribute("value")` what Selenium does is actually get the value of the **property**. You *think* you are getting the value of the attribute, but you are not. Basically, Selenium silently corrects for the misconception that a lot of us initially have when we want to get the current value of an `input` element.

So you JavaScript code does exactly what it should: it return attribute values, but that's not what you need, you need the value of the `value` property.

Comment: Fantastic explanation! You are spot on. Maybe you can help me one step further. My issue lies in that when I enter a certain vlan input value it causes an unexpected error. I am trying to figure out why this error is occurring without having access to the javascript source code. My thought was that maybe an additional attribute is added when it is in 'error state' that might provide a clue as to why the error is being raised on a valid input. Note this error is only raised when the value is changed via selenium and not manually updated.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind based on the description you give here. I would suggest posting a new question that includes the relevant Selenium code, the relevant HTML and JavaScript, and a detailed description of what you are seeing.