# Finding all HTML elements with attribute names that starts with 'aria'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, wai-aria

Using XPath in Selenium or BeautifulSoup in Python, how can one get the tag-names (here 'a', 'button') and the values of 'aria' attributes (here Home, True, False) by knowing that those attributes start with 'aria'

```
<a aria-label="Home" id="1" />
<button aria-hidden="True" id="2" />
<button aria-pressed="False" id="2" />
```

Currently, I have to put in all attributes one-by-one, like this

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@aria-label]")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@aria-pressed]")
```

What I need is something like (which, here, isn't correct),

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*@[starts-with('aria')]")
```

Comment: checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307131/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-find-all-of-an-elements-attributes