# How I can get HTML tags where located some text

Tags: python, selenium

I have some text, like `message`

I have a method who search this last message:

```
def get_message_text(self):
    return self.get_elements(f"//*[@data-qa='Paragraph-message-text']")[-1].text
```

this text in HTML looks like this:

```
<h1><strong><em>message</em></strong></h1>
```

what the method will look like, which output:

`em, strong, h1`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium webdriver: How do I find ALL of an element's attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307131/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-find-all-of-an-elements-attributes)

Comment: @vitaliis this works, but i need tags, not attributes.. i need ```em, strong, h1```, your decision returns 'Paragraph-message-text', almost, but..

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the web element all that you need to get it's tag name(s) is
`String tag = element.getTagName();`
In case the element has several tags you will have to split tag names from the `tag` string.
My code syntax is in `Java` however it's quite similar to `Python`