# Selenium WebElement List of Attributes

Tags: python, selenium, web, webdriver

In especially Python, after finding web elements, I don't actually know which attributes it has. So I can't work efficiently.
An example:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("someclass")
print(element.get_attrubite("class"))
```

InnerHTML, outerHTML, class, value are some of the attributes I know. Is there a list of all attributes that we can get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question [Selenium webdriver: How do I find ALL of an element's attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307131/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-find-all-of-an-elements-attributes) you can find what you are looking for.

It mentions using the command **execute_script**() along with your webdriver.

Comment: Thanks but there are two other attributes that I know, innerHTML and outerHTML, and I can't get them with these answers. Is there another common attributes?