# How to get HTML code of a WebElement in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new at testing so my apologies in advance if my question sounds a bit primary.

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test.

I know that 
`webElement.getAttribute("innerHTML");` brings me the innerHTML, for example for the element below:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button" style="position: absolute; border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
</a>
```

it returns:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
```

but I need something that brings me the inner attribute of WebElement "a", something like below:

```
href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button" style="position: absolute; border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;"
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681897/getting-all-attributes-from-an-iwebelement-with-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 40):

If you want the HTML of the element itself, you can use

```
webElement.getAttribute("outerHTML");
```

It will return the HTML of the element itself plus all the children elements. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want. I don't think there is a way to just get the HTML of the selected element only.

Answer (score 13):

You can read innerHTML attribute to get source of the content of the element or outerHTML for source with the current element.

Example :-
Now suppose your Element is as below

```
<tr id="myRow"><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
```

Inner element Output

```
<td>A</td><td>B</td>
```

Outer element Output

```
<tr id="myRow"><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
```

Live Example :-

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/JavascriptDemo/f/find_out_the_difference_between_innerhtml_and_outerhtml_in_javascript_example.htm

Below you will find the syntax which require as per different binding. Change the `innerHTML` to `outerHTML` as per required.

Python:

```
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Java:

```
elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

C#:

```
element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Ruby:

```
element.attribute("innerHTML")
```

JS:

```
element.getAttribute('innerHTML');
```

If you want whole page HTML use below code :-

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
webElement.getAttribute("href");
webElement.getAttribute("class");
.
.
.
```

or to get them all:

```
Object[] attr = ((JavascriptExecutor)seleniumdriver).executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes);", webElement);
```

Comment: but what if I do not know what attributes that web element may have ?

Comment: edited to include generic method to get all arguments - it should return a List.

Comment: any way that I can not use jacascript?

Comment: it is giving me this error:  unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: How about getting the innerHTML of the parent?

Comment: Try assigning the Javascript output to an Object[] and see what happens.  You shouldn't get a maximum call stack size error.

Comment: The Javascript version is cute, but it has a misplaced closed paren that (for me, working in Chrome) caused :
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Unexpected token ')'
The correct code is:
String allAttributes = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes;", element);

Comment: Oops!  I meant:   ArrayList<String> allAttributes = (ArrayList<String>)((JavascriptExecutor)Common.driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes;", element);

Answer (score 2):

Try `.getAttribute("innerHTML");`function to extract source in string form

Example code:

```
String source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/script[6]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Answer (score 2):

If we have this:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"
style="position: absolute; border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
```

and we need to get all attributes of "a" which will be this:

```
href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"
    style="position: absolute; border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;"
```

We can use this code:

```
webElement.getAttribute("outerHTML").split(">")[0]
```

where webElement is "a".

Or more precisely:

```
String s = we.getAttribute("outerHTML");

s = s.substring(2, s.indexOf(">"));
```

Comment: Why on earth it got that -1 ??? I myself posted this question and this is the perfect answer that I found for it

Answer (score 0):

I usually get a source of the element in my test cases to assert.  See the following code in which I am testing whether or not it is a single-option dropdown.

In the following code, first I got the outer source code of the element and checked whether or not it is having "Multiple" keyword in it.

```
   @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='col-lg-10']//div[1]//div[1]//div[2]//select[1]")
   WebElement element;
   Boolean status = element.getAttribute("outerHTML").contains("Multiple");
   Assert.assertTrue(!status, "User can select only one value at a time in drop down field.");
```

In my case, it asserted that there is no "Multiple" keyword in outer HTML of the select tag and dropdown is a single-selection dropdown.