# Maximum call stack size exceeded, after using: ((JavascriptExecutor)seleniumdriver). executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes);", webElement);

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234205/how-to-get-html-code-of-a-webelement-in-selenium/32234746?noredirect=1#comment52352337_32234746) I am using

```
((JavascriptExecutor)seleniumdriver).
executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes);", webElement);
```

to get all attributes from webElement, but it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.134)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.17.340124 (8cdfc496335a58cfb8bdd672c7dce0c23456384b),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4.25 seconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'sina-PC', ip: '10.55.0.131', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was missing a '('.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)seleniumdriver)
    .executeScript("return (arguments[0].attributes);", webElement);
```