# Find all tags with href attribute using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to find all tags with 'href' attribute of a webpage using selenium. But the methods available are tag specific. example: find_element_by_*()
I want the code to be tag independent. i.e get all tags that have a href attribute.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
all_tags = [el.tag_name for el in elements]
print(all_tags)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath or CSS Selectors.

```
>>> driver.get('https://www.python.org')
>>>
>>> len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[href]'))
241
>>> len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]'))
241
```

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

**I will reference this post:https://stackoverflow.com/a/27307235/15303240**

It is **not possible** using a selenium webdriver API, but you can [*execute a javascript code* to get all attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681897/getting-all-attributes-from-an-iwebelement-with-selenium-webdriver):

```
driver.execute_script('var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', element)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
>>> 
>>> element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="network-items"]/a')
>>> attrs = driver.execute_script('var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', element)
>>> pprint(attrs)
{u'class': u'topbar-icon icon-site-switcher yes-hover js-site-switcher-button js-gps-track',
 u'data-gps-track': u'site_switcher.show',
 u'href': u'//stackexchange.com',
 u'title': u'A list of all 132 Stack Exchange sites'}
```

---

For completeness sake, an alternative solution would be to get the tag's `outerHTML` and parse the attributes using an HTML parser. Example (using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
>>> attrs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').a.attrs
>>> print(attrs)
{u'class': [u'topbar-icon',
            u'icon-site-switcher',
            u'yes-hover',
            u'js-site-switcher-button',
            u'js-gps-track'],
 u'data-gps-track': u'site_switcher.show',
 u'href': u'//stackexchange.com',
 u'title': u'A list of all 132 Stack Exchange sites'}
```